# Is there any way to provide individual Google calendar for each users in a Website?

Tags: php, iframe, google-api, google-calendar-api

Is there any way to provide individual Google calendar for each  users in a Website?.Now i am giving a public calender for all users in my website using the embedded code from Google calender settings.

```
<iframe src="https://calendar.google.com/calendar/embed?src=98uemon8cqggilli0hkpbd8vno%40group.calendar.google.com&ctz=Asia/Calcutta" style="border: 0" width="800" height="600" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

But my requirement is that  when a user registered in to my site a new Google calender will be allocated to the new user. The new user will be able to add new events as private.Is there any way to achieve this?